# Scrapy: How can I execute a CMD command?

Tags: cmd, scrapy

How can I execute a cmd line from within a Scrapy script?  I'm using Scrapy in a Microsoft Windows environment.

Normally, from within native Python, I would do something like this:

```py
import os
os.system('cmd /c "color a"')
```

How can I do something similar from within a Scrapy script?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem.

```
import subprocess

# Command line you want to execute
command = 'your_command_here'.

# Execute the command
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```